# javascript compare two dates and throw an alert

Tags: javascript, date

I have two dates  in DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS format ,i want to compare two dates and throw an

alert .

I tried the below code,but it is not working.

```
startdate = "14/12/2014  19:00:00";
enddate = "21/01/2015  19:00:00";

if(new Date(startdate) > new Date(enddate))
{
    alert("End date cannot be less than start date");

}
```

Comment: What error did you getting ?

Comment: `alert(Date(startdate))` - its not what you think it is. Use a valid date constructor format or create a date by parsing out date parts from the string and calling the serial constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a Date using the following constructors:

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, month[, date[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

You have used the third of them, where the `dateString` is a

> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format
>   recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822
>   timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

The string you have provided hasn't the correct format. Hence the corresponding date objects haven't been created.

I would prefer using the last constructor, since I wouldn't have to format correspondingly the strings.

```
var startDate = new Date(2014,12,14,19,0,0);
var endDate = new Date(2015,1,21,19,0,0);
```

I swapped the `startDate` with the `endDate`, in order we see the alert.

```js
var endDate = new Date(2014,12,14,19,0,0);
var startDate = new Date(2015,1,21,19,0,0);

if(startDate > endDate)
{
    alert("End date cannot be less than start date");
}
```