# JavaScript: Comparing two dates no output

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I would like to compare the given date in the below format in JaveScript. I have tried the following,

> Thu May 19 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
>
> Thu May 20 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

```
var ExpiryDate = userAccount.ExpiryDate();
var datetoday = new Date();
var Expired = (DateTime.Compare(ExpiryDate, datetoday) == -1 ) ? true : false; 
//if expiry date is less than today date then var expired should be true
```

But didn't worked. I could not compare those two dates. It results in un handled exception. Is there any other way to do this date comparison in JaveScript ?

I have referred the following answers in SO but they are in different date format. So that I have raised this question,

1. [javascript compare two dates and throw an alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900943/javascript-compare-two-dates-and-throw-an-alert)
2. [Javascript comparing two dates has wrong result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006724/javascript-comparing-two-dates-has-wrong-result)
3. [Compare two dates in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657733/compare-two-dates-in-javascript)
4. [Javascript compare two dates to get a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162435/javascript-compare-two-dates-to-get-a-difference)

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Date Object Comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606798/javascript-date-object-comparison)

Comment: If they are date objects, you can use `d1 < d2` or `d1 > d2`

Comment: what is DateTime object?

Comment: You can use `getTime()` method to turn Date objects to timestamps. `ExpiryDate.getTime() == datetoday.getTime()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = new Date(); 
//# => Fri May 20 2016 16:09:43 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)


var date2 = new Date();
date2.setDate(date.getDate() - 1); 
//# => Thu May 19 2016 16:09:43 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

date > date2 //# => true
```

Answer (score 0):

use getTime()

```
var date1 = (new Date("20 May 2016")).getTime();
var date2 = (new Date("19 May 2016")).getTime();

date1>date2
```

You will find some good method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)